# Convert string to dictionary with counts of variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a snippet of the output:

```
           {...,"resultMap":
            {..."SEARCH_RESULTS":
             [{..."resultList":[
              {"userClientId":"1"","preferenceValues":["48","51","94"],"MyDate":"7/26/2017 8:30:00 AM"},
              {"userClientId":"2","preferenceValues":["42","11","84"],"MyDate":"7/26/2017 9:40:00 AM"},
              {"userClientId":"3","preferenceValues":["4","16","24"],"MyDate":"7/26/2017 4:20:00 PM"},
              {"userClientId":"4","preferenceValues":["7","2","94"],"MyDate":"7/27/2017 8:00:00 AM"},
              {"userClientId":"1","preferenceValues":["48","22","94"],"MyDate":"7/27/2017 1:50:00 PM"},
              {"userClientId":"2","preferenceValues":["42","11"],"MyDate":"7/27/2017 2:00:00 PM"},
              {"userClientId":"3","preferenceValues":["4","24"],"MyDate":"7/27/2017 6:15:00 PM"},
              {"userClientId":"4","preferenceValues":"7","MyDate":"7/27/2017 9:30:00 PM"}]
             }]
            }
           }
```

I am looking to get a variable pageIdCount that is in dictionary format, where the key is page_id and the values are a counts of occurrences of page_id, by user_id. So for userId 1 it should look like:

```
{"userClientId":"1","preferenceValues":{48:2, 51:1, 94:2, 22:1}}
```

Note that when there is only 1 variable inside preferenceValues- there are no brackets. There is also a field "preferenceValue" where there are no brackets no matter what and it is identical to "preferenceValues" otherwise.

Is that possible?

In Python 2.7, I specify user, password and url and then I have the following:

```
req = requests.post(url = url, auth=(user, password))
ans = req.json()

print ["resultMap"]["SEARCH_RESULTS"][0]["resultList"]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The output doesn't look like anything like a dictionary, so it's hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do. But from your description you might solve this with [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#counter-objects) from the standard library.

Comment: Uh, what exactly do you mean by a "dictionary-like output", do you simply mean with semi-colons?

Comment: Do you need help to simply extract the data out of your JSON output, or for the actual logic of keys and counts into a dictionnary ?

Comment: Also, you say that is "the delimited output of a JSON", but *what exactly are you working with?* A text file?

Comment: Corrected, hope this is better

Comment: @edost4, how are those rows delivered?  Are they all elements in a json array?  Or do you get them one at a time?

Comment: Elements in a json array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_data # this is your data
final_data = {}
for line in yourdata:
    uid = line["userId"]
    pids = line["PageId"]
    if uid not in final_data :
        final_data[uid] = {}
    for pid in pids :
        pid = int(pid)
        if pid not in final_data[uid]:
            final_data[uid][pid]=0
        final_data[uid][pid] += 1
res = [{"userId":uid,"PageIDCount":pids} for uid,pids in final_data.items()]
```

I suppose you are beginning, if so, the most tricky part of this code will probably be the last line, it uses list comprehension. here is [a good lesson](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) about it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154399/discussion-on-answer-by-nicolas-david-convert-string-to-dictionary-with-counts-o).